# Data table subsetting with quotted columns lacks vectorization

Tags: r, data.table

I found that when I use data table and subset a row and a column using quoted strings and try to multiply the result to a vector does not multiply all of the values but only the first value. Is there a reason for this behavior?

```
library(data.table)

v1 <- seq(1,10)

dtab <- data.table('a' = v1)
dframe <- data.frame('a' = v1)

dframe$a * dtab[2, "a"]
# a
# 1: 2

dtab$a * dtab[2, "a"]
# a
# 1: 2

dframe$a * dtab[2, a]
#  2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

dtab$a * dframe[2, 'a']
#  2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

packageVersion('data.table')
# 1.12.8
```

Comment: there is a reason, so user can access data of a vector directly, or as a column in data.table, up to the user which he chose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dtab[2, "a"]` is still a `data.table` with one row,

```
str(dtab[2, "a"])
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ a: int 2
```

while the below results in a `vector`

```
str(dtab[2, a])
#int 2
```

According to `?data.table`

> As long as j returns a list, each element of the list becomes a column in the resulting data.table. When the output of j is not a list, the output is returned as-is (e.g. x[ , a] returns the column vector a), unless by is used, in which case it is implicitly wrapped in list for convenience (e.g. x[ , sum(a), by=b] will create a column named V1 with value sum(a) for each group).
>
> When j is a vector of column names or positions to select (as in data.frame). There is no need to use with=FALSE anymore.

we can convert it to a vector with `[[1]]` or `unlist` and then do the multiplication

```
dframe$a * dtab[2, "a"][[1]] 
#[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

If we have a `data.table/data.frame`, the unit is a column and not the element in the column